I want to implement two interceptors in the angular application one for user and admin for auhentication
the users request only go through user interceptor and admin request only go through admin interceptor how can  I separate them in the providers in the app.module.ts
providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withFetch())
    ,CookieService,MessageService,
     provideAnimations(),
     {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
      useClass: AdminAuthInterceptor,
       multi: true},
       {provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass:UserAuthInterceptor,
       }
      ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}) 
export class AppModule { }

how to provide the two interceptors separately in the app.module.ts

I don't think this is how you should be doing it. I'd add both and make them only intercept if they should...

You can try to use a factory that will return AdminAuthInterceptor or UserAuthInterceptor depending on your current user type.
providers definition in module
providers: [..., 
   { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,  
     useFactory: authInterceptorFactory, 
     deps: [UserService]
   },
   ...]

factory definition
const authInterceptorFactory= (userService: UserService) =>  {
    return userService.isUserAdmin() ? new AdminAuthInterceptor() : new UserAuthInterceptor();
};

https://angular.dev/guide/di/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers-usefactory
